# Going to another Activity in Robotium

Tags: android, ui-automation, robotium

I'm new to Robotium and Android testing, lately I tested iOS apps. Now I am testing Android application, and on the first Activity I enter email and password, so when it is done, I press the Enter button on the keyboard and the next activity should appear. How can I implement it in my test?
I have this in the beginnihg of test:

```
    EditText etEnterEmail = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.EditText01);
    solo.clearEditText(etEnterEmail);
    solo.enterText(etEnterEmail, "anna@gmail.com");

    EditText etEnterPassword = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.editText2);
    solo.clearEditText(etEnterPassword);
    solo.enterText(etEnterPassword, "qwerty123");
```

How can I press the button Enter? When the test is running the keyboard doesn't even appear, strings are just appearing in EditTexts. Plase help me! I'm desperate!

Answer (score 2):

You can send it via

```
solo.sendKey(Solo.ENTER);
```

After that you can check whether your `Activity` is being displayed by asserting:

```
assertTrue(solo.waitForActivity(expectedClass.getSimpleName()));
```

Comment: I tried that, no reaction... Test stops and application closes, the next activity still doesn't appear... Maybe smth I should import?

Comment: I have added the code you want to add in order to wait for your expected activity to my answer above.

Comment: This means your activity is not being displayed within the default waiting time.

Comment: Is it normal that during the test(when EditTexts are compliting) the keyboard is not shown? Maybe that's why it can't press on Enter? Cause it doesn'f see it?

Comment: I found a solution.   solo.clickOnView(etEnterPassword);
                  solo.sendKey(Solo.ENTER);
Thanks anyway! It's great that there are people who care!

Answer (score 0):

if the keyboard doesn't show maybe try `solo.TypeText()`

tty if this code works for you:

```
EditText etEnterEmail = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.EditText01);
solo.clearEditText(etEnterEmail);
solo.TypeText(etEnterEmail, "anna@gmail.com");

EditText etEnterPassword = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.editText2);
solo.clearEditText(etEnterPassword);
solo.TypeText(etEnterPassword, "qwerty123");
solo.senkey(solo.ENTER);
solo.assertCurrentActivity("check for activity", your_activity.class) //your_activity ex: MainActivity,...
```